# Resolving cameraProvider when implemting video Recorder with camera X

Tags: kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

i am implementing an android application in kotlin to record video with front camera but i've enconter a problem with a class that i can't resolve (cameraProvider) but i've imported specific camera x libraries for video recording :

```
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-alpha07'
```

here is the code i have impemented :

```
    private fun configVideo() {


       //enter the prioritized resolution and if none of them is available , fallback with the quality record

       val qualitySelector = QualitySelector.fromOrderedList(
           listOf(Quality.UHD, Quality.FHD, Quality.HD, Quality.SD),
           FallbackStrategy.lowerQualityOrHigherThan(Quality.SD))

        //first step , liez video capture
        //-Creer un Recorder pour l'enregistrement de la video

       val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
           .setExecutor(cameraExecutor)
           .setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
           .build()
       val videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

       try {
           // Bind use cases to camera
           cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
               this, CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA,  videoCapture)
       } catch(exc: Exception) {
           Log.e("TAG", "Use case binding failed", exc)
       }

    }
```

cameraProvider is signaled red with message : Unresolved reference: cameraProvider . How could i resolve it   ?

Answer (score 1):

`import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider`

It should be in `androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-alpha07`